# How to determine accuracy of multimeter?

Tags: voltage, multimeter, error

I have two multimeter of local brand both work good but both have slightly different Reading.
When i check it with 7805 ic voltage one says 4.91V and one says 5.12V. I know its very low differance but if one of this multimeter have error how can i know which one have error?

Comment: What if you switch the probes?

Comment: Same result (as expected)

Comment: You have to compare them to a known voltage, or to a multimeter that you know is accurate. If you can't do either, you will never know which one (if any of them) is accurate.

Comment: You say "both work good", but if they're that far apart then at least one works horribly.

Comment: A 7805 IC is not a precision voltage source, so it is not a good reference to calibrate a precision instrument like a multimeter. Even a cheap multimeter could have a better accuracy than the 7805.

Comment: A sample 7805 can have an initial output voltage between 4.8 to 5.2V, [according to TI datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slvs056p/slvs056p.pdf).

Comment: A 7805 regulator is an pretty inaccurate reference to use, +/- 5% output means 4.75..5.25 V. Anyway, has it got a load across it? At the very least, load the 7805 with a 470 R resistor to draw 10-odd mA and keep it stable. Otherwise its driving into a megohms load. Have another go after that. (Not expecting earth-shaking changes, needs doing though.)

Comment: What meters are those? If they are cheapos, chances are both are still within spec

Comment: if you have more than one 7805 you can begin to whittle down the margin of error, but a fresh AA should have closer to 1.6v

Comment: voltage reference is a different IC from voltage regulator. voltage standard is again something else.

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://www.keysight.com/main/editorial.jspx?ckey=129529&id=129529&nid=-11143.0.00&lc=eng&cc=IR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is either that you cannot or it's easy. It depends on your definition of "cheap". The difference that you cite is more than 4%, which is more than you should be dealing with. At least one of those meters is badly off.

What you need is a reference voltage.A good starting point would be the LT1236, which should cost you about 4 dollars plus shipping from Digikey. This will give you a 5 volt output with an accuracy of 0.1%. If this is too much for you, a TL431 will cost 40 cents, but its accuracy will only be 1%. There are lots of other parts which will do the same thing, and lots of suppliers, so get on the web and do some research. And just as a bit of advice, you're better off with a 0.1% unit.

An alternative would be to find someone with a good meter and ask to use it to check yours.

Comment: You can also always try and get samples. I know a bunch of people who use ADR4520BRZ as their reference, since analog doesn't seem to mind handing them out for free.